Enable Forecasting on scratch via CLI with Most Likely value
here's the situation... We configured CI/CD with workflow in Github. In the short description it: creates the sandbox, deploys the whole code from the branch to it, and runs all apex tests.
Now we want to enable Forecasting and use add new value to Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName with Most Likely Status Category. As I read the documentation the order during manually setting this feature I Have to: enable forecasting, and MANUALLY add picklist value on Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName field.
Now when I push the whole code to the branch and perform push code to scratch there is an issue. I can't deploy Forecasting.settings because it has references to the Most Likely Status Category. It needs to be used during the manual creation of the picklist value Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName.
So the point is:

How to enable Forecasting without using Forecasting.settings (because ours has references to Most likely) to have access to Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName field?
How to add a new picklist value on Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName with Most value category?
How to push the whole code successfully with those requirements, fields, and references to Forecasting?
It needs to be automatic and written in workflow using Salesforce CLI. Any advices?

